# ggplot with JQuery Datepicker; can I use this to add interactivity to the html markdown output (Shiny not suitable)?

Tags: jquery, r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I have a very large dataframe of historical data of which this is a clipping (data=historic):

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(18948, 18948, 18948, 18948, 
18949, 18949, 18949, 18949, 18950, 18950, 18950, 18950, 18951, 
18951, 18951, 18951, 18952, 18952, 18952, 18952, 18953, 18953, 
18953, 18953, 18954, 18954, 18954, 18954, 18955, 18955, 18955, 18955), class = "Date"), 
    cumvol = c(17.572, 17.578, 17.672, 17.829, 17.471, 17.477, 
    17.489, 17.497, 17.527, 17.546, 17.552, 17.557, 17.562, 17.564, 
    17.573, 17.658, 17.688, 17.698, 17.714, 17.743, 17.757, 17.764, 
    17.774, 17.776, 17.787, 17.798, 17.809, 17.82, 17.825, 17.841, 18.101, 18.243
    ), time = structure(c(29674, 29674, 29691, 29719, 29674, 
    29674, 29691, 29719, 29730, 29746, 29749, 29757, 29763, 29768, 
    29782, 29782, 29795, 29796, 29805, 29916, 29919, 29922, 29924, 
    29933, 30004, 30016, 30037, 30048, 30053, 30055, 30075, 30078, 30081), class = c("hms", 
    "difftime"), units = "secs")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -30L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001d92b2d1ef0>)
```

I am currently plotting some recent data over the top of it (data=recent):

```
   structure(list(date = structure(c(19038, 19038, 19038, 19038), class = "Date"), 
    cumvol = c(0.029, 0.034, 0.07, 0.075), time = structure(c(29674, 
    29674, 29691, 29719), class = c("hms", "difftime"), units = "secs")), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001d92b2d1ef0>)
```

Using the following code (most_recent simply takes the most recent datapoint from 'recent'):

```
ggplot()+geom_line(data=historic,aes(x=time, y=cumvol, group=date),color='#BAB0AC', alpha=0.5)+
  geom_line(data=recent,aes(x=time, y=cumvol, group=date),size=1.2,color='#E15758')+
  geom_point(data=most_recent, aes(x=time,y=cumvol), color='#E15759',size=3)+geom_hline(yintercept = 0)+  theme(title=element_text(size=12),panel.background = element_rect(fill='white',color='black'),legend.position='right')+
    labs(title = "Morning Vol",subtitle = "Cum Vol so far", x = "Time", y = "Vol")
```

What I'd like to do is give viewers of the html file (produced by the markdown) the ability to highlight some specific dates (from 'historic') and compare it to the data from 'recent'. Now I realise this would probably be possible in a shiny app, however that is not suitable for my purposes and I was wondering whether jQuery's 'Datepicker' plugin (or something similar) might offer the solution.

Does anyone know how (or if) I can achieve this?

https://www.aliciaschep.com/blog/js-rmarkdown/

Comment: You want the end-user to be able to open an HTML file, interact with the DatePicker plugin, and have the `ggplot2`-based plots change? Unless I am misunderstanding ... there is no way to get `ggplot2`, an R-based package, to function outside of R. I believe plotly may be able to do what you want (idk, I'm not good at it), though you'll need to shift graphic engines to do so.

Comment: I'm not necessarily wedded to using ggplot to generate the chart, the functionality for the user to be able to select particular dates to highlight in the rmarkdown html output is the real attraction. Though due to the fact that the full dataset contains '000s of observations, using a feature like plotly makes the file far too large to be usable.

Comment: You just talked yourself out of an HTML file, right? That is, in an HTML file you have some plot-rendering options but none of them R: plotly is just one example, but the issue you highlighted (000's of data) will be an issue for all js-based plotting engines. If you cannot place the data in the HTML file itself, or you cannot render the plot itself in the HTML file itself, then you need to have javascript reach out to a "server" somewhere to subset the data or render the plot. `Rserve`, `plumber`, and `opencpu` are three ways this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to r2evans, it seems I had to slice the dataset down in to a more manageable selection then use the crossstalk library to add interactivity.